# Unimplemented feature error in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I sm getting error:

```
ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
ORA-06512: at "SYS.CHANGE_SSAN", line 127
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
```

on this line :

```
  alter_constraints_disable(hosm_list.hosm);
```

This is the procedure:

```
PROCEDURE alter_constraints_disable (hosm_cd   IN VARCHAR2)

IS
    BEGIN

    for constraint_list IN (select table_name, constraint_name 
                                   from dba_constraints 
                                   where owner=hosm_cd 
                                   and constraint_name in ('List of constraints removed for space.'))
    LOOP
        execute immediate 'alter table '||hosm_cd||'.'||constraint_list.table_name||' DISABLE constraint '||constraint_list.constraint_name;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The issue appears to be coming from the next line instead of the call to alter_constraints_disable.

execute immediate 'select person_id bulk collect into dup_ssan from '||hosm_list.hosm||'.dod_per order by 1 asc';

Is there something I am missing about bulk collect

Comment: You shouldn't build your own objects in the SYS schema.  That schema is part of the Oracle install, and messing with it can break your database.

Comment: It's only on a server being used to scramble PII and touches every schema in the database. It seemed to make sense to temporarily put it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better exception handling will uncover exactly what is causing the error.  Run this modified version and then post the output.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE alter_constraints_disable (hosm_cd IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    BEGIN

    for constraint_list IN (select table_name, constraint_name 
                                   from dba_constraints 
                                   where owner=hosm_cd 
                                   and constraint_name in ('List of constraints removed for space.'))
    LOOP
        DECLARE
            v_sql varchar2(32767);
        BEGIN
            execute immediate 'alter table '||hosm_cd||'.'||constraint_list.table_name||
                ' DISABLE constraint '||constraint_list.constraint_name;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Error with '||constraint_list.table_name||'.'||
                constraint_list.constraint_name);
            v_sql := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', constraint_list.table_name, hosm_cd);
            dbms_output.put_line('Table that caused the error:'||chr(10)||v_sql);
            raise;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

**UPDATE**

The `bulk collect into` should not be inside the dynamic SQL string.  Here's an example:

```
create table dod_per as select level person_id from dual connect by level <= 100;

declare
    type dup_ssan_type is table of number;
    dup_ssan dup_ssan_type;
    v_owner varchar2(30) := user;
begin
    execute immediate 'select person_id from '||v_owner||'.dod_per order by 1 asc'
    bulk collect into dup_ssan;
end;
/
```

Comment: Tryed that and got the same error. Which makes me think the error might be coming from somewhere else and just saying its here.

Comment: It is meant to generate the same error, but it will also tell you which table and constraint generated the error.  If you're executing the procedure in SQL*Plus you'll need to run `set serveroutput on` to see the results.  Or you may want to write the information in some logging or temporary table.

Comment: I figured out the issue before the answer got posted on here but you are 100% correct as to what the issue was. Thanks for the help and your time.

Answer (score 2):

DBA_CONSTRAINTS is only available to users with DBA role. Try with ALL_CONSTRAINTS or USER_CONSTRAINTS. Also make sure that the user executing the procedure has the ALTER CONSTRAINT privilege.

What version of Oracle are you using? If it's express edition, then some features will not be enabled because you need a license, but disabling/enabling constraints is not one of them as far as I remember.

Comment: It's on 11g enterprise

Comment: That's weird. You shouldn't have disabled features in Enterprise Edition. I also tested your procedure and it executed ok.

Comment: Ok, try adding KEEP INDEX after the DISABLE command. It shoud look like execute immediate 'alter table '||hosm_cd||'.'||constraint_list.table_name||' DISABLE constraint '||constraint_list.constraint_name||' KEEP INDEX;

Comment: @tilley31 I think you're confusing `ORA-03001: unimplemented feature` with `ORA-00439: feature not enabled`.  "Unimplemented" means something like "what you're trying to do makes sense, we just haven't gotten around to coding it yet."

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, I also received this error via the ODP.NET provider when my query had an identifier with an extra trailing double-quote (something like this)

```
SELECT "Field1" "Alias1", "Field2" "Alias2"
FROM "SomeSchema"."SomeTable"" -- <- extra quote
WHERE "SomeField" = 'SomeCriteria'
```

Strange error for a simple typo.